# How to ignore json property in encapsulated design

Tags: java, jaxb, jackson, encapsulation

```
class A{ 
   private B b; 
   //other properties
   //getter setter
}
// unable to add jsonIgnore in this class due to dependency in other module
class B {
   int id;
   String name;
   String defname;
}
```

I want to ignore `defname` in class `A` JSON building by `codehaus.jackson` API.

I need `{a:{id:value,name:value}}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Mixin](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations) for this purpose.

- First Create an abstract class with JsonIgnore annotation:

  ```
  abstract class MixIn{
       @JsonIgnore
       abstract String getDefname(); }
  ```
- Then use it as below. (Be sure your getter name of defName field as getDefName() in your B class or change it in Mixin class as yours.)

  ```
  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  objectMapper.addMixIn( B.class, MixIn.class );
  objectMapper.writeValue( System.out, new A() );
  ```

This prints:

```
{"b":{"id":1,"name":"Sercan"}}
```

Comment: Hey i am restricted to modify class B

Comment: May be i am not explain problem properly the object mapper is already written. and the class extend some other class.

Comment: The only way is modifying the object mapper, otherwise you have to do a nasty String parse and remove process that is not recommended in any world.